# How to execute arbitrary command after Stopping the Current running bash file

Tags: angularjs, bash, intellij-idea, cygwin

I have this bash file that I used to run My angular application:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

yarn start
```

I am running this file via IntelliJ IDEA "Run/Debug Configurations" menu as a Runnable target.

**The question is**: when I ask IDEA to stop the bash run, it stopped it but doesn't kill the node process and I got the port still open.

My workaround was to edit the bash file to look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "cleaning from previous run...."
ps -W | awk '/node.exe/,NF=1' | xargs kill -f
echo "done cleaning"

yarn start
```

P.S. I am using Cygwin in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using special exit trap:

```
trap 'clean_exit' EXIT

clean_exit() {
    ps -W | awk '/node.exe/,NF=1' | xargs kill -f
}
```

trap registers `clean_exit` at exit.